# Webkit bug toggling between display:table-cell and inline-block when triggered with media query

Tags: css, media-queries

http://jsfiddle.net/YHJrV/2/

Can any CSS gurus figure out why webkit has issues toggling between display:table-cell and inline block when triggered with a media query?

In webkit, drag the vertical divider left/right to trigger the media query and watch the list behavior act goofy.

Is this a bug? TIA

Comment: Hopefully this helps someone, but thanks to the ever so generous @snookca, the solution was to apply display:table-row to the UL.

Bada-bing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone, but thanks to the ever so generous @snookca, the solution was to apply `display:table-row` to the UL. Bada-bing!

Answer (score 4):

It's a [known bug in webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53166).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with `display:table-row` toggling to `display:block`. I also had a container div with `display:table`. To fix that I set the container div to `display:block`.

Comment: By changing the container's display value from table to block you also lose other table properties like table-layout, etc. :( In my case I just used display: inline-table to force refresh.