# Layout breaks only when I drop below my break point and expand past it again

Tags: html, css, webkit, media-queries

SOLVED:  See answer below.  I'd still love to know WHY this happened and why the fix worked.

UPDATE: Could my problem be related to this webkit bug:

[Bug 53166: 'display' styles in media queries don’t get re-applied correctly after resizing](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53166)?

When my desktop-size media query kicks in, something happens to my nav bar that doesn't "unhappen" when the window width drops back below that size.  The issue only appears to happen in Chrome or Safari.  I believe it has to do with the `display` property, and it feels like a bug.

[You can see the behavior here.](http://dev.citylightphilly.com)

To reproduce mobile menu problem, start with Chrome / Safari or iPad Safari.

1. Start with browser wider than 1023px (landscape on iPad)
2. Make browser smaller than 1024px (or rotate iPad)
3. Click Menu -- problem #1 appears

[image: Mobile Menu Screenshot]

To reproduce desktop menu problem

1. Start with browser wider than 1023px
2. Make browser smaller than 1024px
3. Make browser wider than 1023px again
4. Problem #2 appears

[image: Desktop Menu Screenshot]

**Notes:**

- If I start below 1024px, everything works great.
- If I start below 1024px enlarge the window over 1024px, everything works great.
- If I start above 1024px, everything works great.
- This ONLY breaks if I start above 1023px and resize lower.

I think the issue has something to do with the the table-cell CSS property I'm using, but I can't figure it out.

There's some JS going on here but the problem appears even with JS disabled.

For now I'll include the Header HTML / CSS in hopes that the answer is something simple.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="/assets/logo.png" />
    <button id="toggle" class="closed"></button>
</div>
<div class="spacer clearfix"></div>
<div id="nav">      
    <ul class="primary-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Sundays</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Citygroups</a></li>
        <li class="desktop-logo"><a href="#"><img src="/assets/logo.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discipleship</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sermons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS, including the Media Queries

```
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #FFF;
}

img.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 40.3125%;  /* 129px / 320px */
  margin: 24px 0 23px 9.375%; /* 24 0 23 30 */  
}

.spacer {
  height: 70px;
}

/* Main Nav */

button#toggle {
  float: right;
  border: none;
  width: 6.5625%;
  min-height: 23px;
  margin: 24px 9.375% 23px 34.375%; 
  padding: 0;
  background: url(assets/nav-toggle.png) center no-repeat;
}

button#toggle.opened {
  background: url(assets/nav-toggle-opened.png) center no-repeat;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 70px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 70px);
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.js #nav {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}

#nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #363636;
  border-bottom: solid #1E1E1E 1px;
}

#nav li {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}

#nav li a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: solid #1E1E1E 1px;
  padding: 0 0 0 9.375%;
}

#nav li.desktop-logo { /* Necessary for centered logo on wide displays */
  display: none;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------
             4. HOME - LARGE MOBILE
              - Min-Width: 321px -
---------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 321px) {

    img.logo {
      max-width: 159px;
      margin: 20px 0 21px 7.03125%; /* 20 0 21 54 */    
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 2.7969em;
    }

    h5 {
      font-size: 1.3125em;
    }

}


/*--------------------------------------------------
             4. HOME - MOBILE LANDSCAPE 
               - Min-Width: 321px -
             - Orientation: Landscape -
---------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen 
    and (min-width: 321px) 
    and (max-width: 768px) 
    and (orientation: landscape) {

    .headline {
      display: block;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;  
      overflow: none;
      margin-top: 5%;
    }

}



/*--------------------------------------------------
             4. HOME - SMALL TABLET / LARGE PHONE
                  - Min-Width: 481px -
---------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen 
    and (min-width: 481px) {

    img.logo {
      max-width: 159px;
      margin: 20px 0 21px 7.03125%; /* 20 0 21 54 */    
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 3.3438em;
    }

    h5 {
      font-size: 1.625em;
    }

}



/*--------------------------------------------------
             5. HOME - LARGE TABLET LAYOUT
                  - Min-Width: 601px -
---------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen 
    and (min-width: 601px) {


    h1 {
      font-size: 4.5625em;
    }

    h5 {
      font-size: 2.25em;
    }


}

/*--------------------------------------------------
             5. HOME - DESKTOP LAYOUT - Min-Width: 1024px
---------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen 
    and (min-width: 1024px) {

    .header {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      height: 87px;
      background: none;
      display: none;
    }

    img.logo, .spacer {
      display: none;
    }

    .js #nav {
      position: relative;
    }

    .js #nav.closed {
      max-height: none;
    }

    #nav-toggle {
      display: none;
    }

    button#toggle {
      display: none;
    }

    #nav {
      height: auto;
    }

    #nav ul {
      height: 87px;
      width: 66.6666666667%;
      min-width: 1024px; 
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 0;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    #nav li {
      width: auto;
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-size: .875em;
    }

    #nav li a {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: none;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 87px;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #nav li a, #nav li a:active, #nav li a:visited {
      color: #58585A;
    }

    #nav li a:hover {
      color: #FAAC1D;     
    }

    #nav li.desktop-logo {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 206px;
      padding: 0 20px;
    }

    #nav li.desktop-logo img {
      padding: 0;
    }

    #nav li.desktop-logo a {
      display: inline;
      line-height: 0;
    }

    .flexslider {
      height: -moz-calc(100% - 87px);
      height: -webkit-calc(100% - 87px);
      height: calc(100% - 87px);
    }

    .headline hr {
      width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to be answering so many of my own questions.  No one saw this one.  I'm sure this will help someone.

I saw this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619276/webkit-bug-toggling-between-displaytable-cell-and-inline-block-when-triggered-w) regarding the webkit bug.  Their solution to add display: table-row to the UL tag worked. However, in my situation, I needed the UL to be centered with a width < 100%, both of which weren't possible as a `table-row`.

The final solution was to move `display: table` to the parent div (#nav).  When I did this and removed it from the `<ul>` tag, everything worked perfectly.  I don't know why.

The [original link](http://dev.citylightphilly.com) is updated and working now.

Final working CSS (media query only):

```
/*--------------------------------------------------
             5. HOME - DESKTOP LAYOUT - Min-Width: 1024px
---------------------------------------------------*/

...

    .js #nav {
      position: relative;
      display: table;
    }

...

    #nav ul {
      height: 87px;
      width: 66.6666666667%;
      min-width: 1024px; 
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 0;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
```